# Como obter o nome do computador?

Tags: c#

Como posso obter o "nome do computador" e "Nome do computador completo" usando C#?

Que são os mostrados nas propriedades do computador:

> [image: propriedades do computador]

Comment: Porque é que estão a dizer que a pergunta não é claro ou útil?

Comment: veja a minha resposta.

Comment: já vi! e funcionou é mesmo isso!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O que você se refere como nome completo na verdade é o `MachineName` e o nome do `HostName`. Você pode obetê-lo dessa forma:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var nome = Environment.MachineName;
    var nomeCompleto = Dns.GetHostEntry(nome).HostName;

    Console.WriteLine(nome); //PC-162
    Console.WriteLine(nomeCompleto); //PC-162.meudominio.com.br

    Console.Read();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Para pegar o nome da maquina utilize `Environment.MachineName`:

```
class Sample 
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Nome: {0}", Environment.MachineName);
    }
}
```

Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.machinename(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss vou ser do contra e dizer que talvez responda sim, claro que a resposta ficou bem fraca, então adicione um exemplo.

Answer (score 1):

Para pegar o nome do computado só usar a classe [Environment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.environment.machinename(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var name = Environment.MachineName;
    Console.WriteLine("Nome do computador: {0}", name);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: E como consigo obter o nome completo do computador?

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "nome completo"?

Comment: no painel de controlo tem o "Computer name" e o "Full Computer Name" e falta me esse, mas não encontro em lado nenhum nada que fale dele

Answer (score 0):

Julgo que é usando o "Environment.MachineName", mas não consigo confirmar pois estou a tentar obter o mesmo que você

Comment: É sim o "Environment.MachineName", funciona perfeitamente, use no seu programa também

Comment: Bem, sendo assim vou testar! Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: duas contas da mesma pessoa, sendo que outras duas já foram banidas e suspensa hoje...

Comment: @RovannLinhalis, inclusive a minha resposta original foi para a outra pergunta :)
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/309916/como-obter-o-full-name-do-computador-em-wpfc

Comment: Qual é o mal de depois de verificar que funciona partilhar a resposta com quem precisa? não é por isso que eu sou uma conta fake ou ele, não entendo o que fiz de mal para a comunidade sinceramente....

Comment: tenho culpa de não querer dar a conhecer quem sou? estou neste momento a ser avaliado pelo meu projeto, se não tenho confiança no mundo para dar a cara, é você quem vai obrigar-me a fazê-lo? Repito, antes de acusar, saiba do que fala por favor que é feio fazer acusações completamente irrealistas. Com esta me retiro, um abraço amigo.

Comment: os dois usuários exemplarmente banidos =] até mesmo o número do usuário era próximo um do outro, comprovando a criação praticamente no mesmo instante